# Deploying first repository to Netlify - blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, netlify

I try to deploy my first repository to Netlify and when its done there is blank page and errror in dev tools [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGDLg.png) I am wondering.. is it because of Base directory or Package directory?
[deploy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzvhf.png)

What should I write exactly to Package directory?

I have imported repository from GitHub with these steps

Netlify with Git
Push your code to a git repository (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, Azure DevOps).
Import the project to Netlify.
Choose the branch, output directory, and set up environment variables if applicable.
Click on Deploy.
Your Vite app is deployed!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting a connection refused error could it be an issue with authorization? You have to make sure Netlify is authorized to access your GitHub repo.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).